# How many marbles of the same color must I observe to be confident all the marbles are the same color?

Tags: probability

Let's say I know there are 1,000,000 marbles in a jar, and I don't have any idea what color any of them are.

I draw a marble at random, and it's black. I draw another marble at random, and it's black. I draw a third marble at random, and it's black.

I'm already starting to think that maybe all the marbles are black, but I know I have a really small sample size.

How many (all black) marbles do I have to draw to be (let's say 95%) confident that all the marbles are black? (Something to do with Bayesian inference, right?)

(This could also work with red horses! or black Scottish Sheep!)

Comment: If we assume that there is only one different (say, white) marble, then even 1,000,000 tries (with replacement) might produce only black marbles with probability very close to $\frac1e$, so we are still quite far away from a 95% level. -- However, as you mention Bayes, our a priori or other experience might indicate that jars with marbles do almost never come with just a single outsider - they are either only single-coloured, or there is a greater mix